# Add Mouse Hover Event to ComboBox Items

Tags: javafx, combobox, imageview

How can i have a combo box that when the mouse cursor hovered over combo box items a specific images occur on a specified Image View in JavaFX ?
Here is what i have :

```
    Image myImage1 = new Image("MyImage1.jpg");
    Image myImage2 = new Image("MyImage2.jpg");
    Image myImage3 = new Image("MyImage3.jpg");
    ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();
    ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox();
    myComboBox.getItems().addAll("Item1","Item2","Item3");
    //
    // Mouse Hover for ComboBox items here ...
    //
    // If Item1 Hovered -> ImageView.setImage(myImage1);
    // If Item2 Hovered -> ImageView.setImage(myImage2);
    // If Item3 Hovered -> ImageView.setImage(myImage3);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you have?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for making so much effort.

Comment: But it's the only thing i have, i have not used ComboBox for this kind of action before.

Comment: So, to paraphrase your question: "I have 'a specified `ImageView`'. I have a collection of strings to display in a combo box and I have some mechanism for mapping each string to an image. I am too lazy to make the effort to provide any of this information in my question, but please give me the codez for what I want to do anyway."

Comment: try using ComboBox's `setOnMouseEntered()` method.

Comment: Thanks , for your help on this field and special. But I have a question is this action event for ComboBox items?

Comment: If you really want help, make it easy for us to help you. Write a simple, but complete, application that has all the pieces *except* the part you can't do (it shouldn't take more than about 3 dozen lines of code to do that). Doing that will also make a better question/answer for other users who may want to see it later.

Comment: but i really don't have idea in this field so how you offer me to show more code than what i  have shown?

Comment: You said you have an `ImageView`. Where is it? It is not in the code you posted. You presumably have an `Image` that you want to display when `"Item 1"` is hovered, and an `Image` that you want to display when `"Item 2"` is hovered, etc. Where is the code that creates those images? Again, if you want help, make it as easy as possible for someone to help you. If you don't want help, delete the question.

Comment: I changed it as i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cell factory on the combo box:

```
Image myImage1 = new Image("MyImage1.jpg");
Image myImage2 = new Image("MyImage2.jpg");
Image myImage3 = new Image("MyImage3.jpg");
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView();
ComboBox<String> myComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
myComboBox.getItems().addAll("Item1","Item2","Item3");

Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<>();
images.put("Item1", myImage1);
images.put("Item2", myImage2);
images.put("Item3", myImage3);

myComboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
        }
    };
    cell.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
        if (cell.isEmpty()) {
            myImageView.setImage(null);
        } else {
            myImageView.setImage(images.get(cell.getItem());
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```